# Ajax search result list displaying the index page downwards

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

```html
// search php --- searching for result
    
<?php
$search = $_GET ['search'];
if(strlen($search)<=1)
{
echo "Search term too short";
}
else{
echo "You searched for <b>$search</b> <br size='1'></br>";
require("config.php");
 
$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);
foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
$x++;
if($x==1)
 $construct .="description LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
$construct .="AND description LIKE '%$search_each%'";
 
}
 
$constructs ="SELECT * from products WHERE $construct;";
$run = mysql_query($constructs);
 
$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);
 
if ($foundnum==0)
echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search</b>.</br></br>1. 
Try more general words. for example: If you want to search 'how to create a website'
then use general keyword like 'create' 'website'</br>2. Try different words with similar
 meaning</br>3. Please check your spelling";
else
{
echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";
$i = 0;
// echo "<table cellpadding='01' border='1'>";
// echo "<tr>"; 
while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
{
 $sqltype ="SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id=" . $runrows['cat_id']. ";";
 $typerun =mysql_query($sqltype);
 $typerow =mysql_fetch_assoc($typerun);
$title = $runrows ['name'];
$desc = $runrows ['description'];
$type = $runrows ['type'];
$id = $runrows ['id'];
// echo "<td>";

if(empty($runrows['image'])) {

echo "[<a href='productdetails.php?id=" . $runrows['id']. "&type=" . $typerow['cat_type'] . "'><img src='./productimages/dummy.jpg' alt='". $runrows['name'] . "' size 

= 1></a>]";
}
else {

echo "[<a href='productdetails.php?id=" . $runrows['id']. "&type=" . $typerow['cat_type'] . "'><img src='./productimages/" . $runrows['image']. "' alt='". $runrows

['name'] . "' size = 1></a>]";

}
 
}
}
 
}
?>
```

```js
    
        <script>
        function showResult(str) {
          if (str.length==0) { 
            document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
            document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
            return;
          }
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
              document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
              document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
            }
          }
          xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?search="+str,true);
          xmlhttp.send();
        }
        </script>
```

```html
Index page.
    
    <body>
    <!-- Begin Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper"><!-- Begin Search -->
    <div id="search">
    <div class="shell">
    <form action="search.php" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="container"> <input value="search" title="search" class="blink" type="text" name="search" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)" size="90" />
    </div>
    <input class="search-button" value="submit" type="submit" name="submit"/>
    <div id="livesearch"></div> </form>
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Search --><!-- Begin Header -->
    
    <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

I have a search button on my index page. When I search for anything and press enter , its correctly showing the result into a different page , but when I type anything in the search box , it also showing the result on the same page using ajax. But the drop down result moving the index page downwards . Could you please let me know how to display the result by overlapping the index page. Thanks .

Comment: WHY APP CAPS? and where is your code?

Comment: Just updated the part of index page and search php.

Comment: A lot of JS, PHP and HTML problems. would you mind to double check your syntax first? and you didn't use jQuery at all. Last, stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, use PDO / MySQLi instead.

Comment: There is no syntax error. I have ran it several time . I have been working in mainframe apps. Very new in web designing . The real problem is , after getting the result from searh.php , when i tried to display it in the index page , its moving down the index page content to display the result . Could you please let me know how to resolve this issue .

Comment: pls screenshot your issues.

Comment: No syntax error? You sure? e.g. there is no such thing called `</br>`. Do you mean `<br />`? And the code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: im not able to attach the screen shot due to insufficient credit point. Yes there is no syntax error . As an example , when you click on the inbox in stackoverflow.com , it displays messages in a dropdoen list but it does not move down the index page , rather it overlaps on the index page . But in my case result drop down list moving down the index page while displaying the result.

Comment: @ raptor  , I have managed to fix the displacing issue by adding position : fixed . But search result still overlapped by index page .